# clean standalone, popup launcher for linux desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop-environment, launcher

I have begun to work heavily   by remote connection to Linux servers using [Xpra](https://xpra.org/), frequently opening a variety of  windowed applications.

When connected to a remote host, the Xpra client posts a tray icon  providing a menu of  applications installed on the remote host, but its use is cumbersome compared to the many   launchers running on modern desktop environments. Most launchers available from a local desktop environment are tied to a screen panel or other feature that is not generally included in the items Xpra adds to a desktop, and whose  inclusion would not be desirable. Panels on a desktop are part of the environment provided locally.

Are any recommendations available for stable and friendly application launchers that present as simply a popup window at the center of the screen, from which I might easily select among the applications on the remote host for launching with local display, without fussing with the cumbersome drop-down menu provided by the Xpra tray icon?